# What is the difference between physical device driver and logical device driver?

Tags: hardware, device-driver

I would like to know the difference between the physical device driver (PDD) and the logical device driver (LDD)?

Apart from this difference that the logical device driver (LDD) is written by the operating system vendor, while the physical device driver (PDD) is implemented by the device vendor.

Is there any difference? Do we need both of them to communicate with hardware? What are their individual importance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A logical device driver is a high level abstraction of how a device behaves. A physical device driver is a driver for a specific piece of hardware. The logical device driver talks to the physical device driver for you to keep you abstracted from the underlying hardware.

For example, there are many different types of printers, and they typically come with their own drivers. However, you wouldn't want to have to code your application to deal with all these different drivers. Instead, you talk to the logical driver using the standard printer API, and the logical driver talks to the physical driver for you. It's the job of the physical device driver vendor to ensure that their driver integrates into the logical device driver model.

The logical/physical divide exists throughout more modern operating systems. For example, you don't have to worry about which graphics card you are using, instead you talk to the graphics API of your operating system, and it knows how to communicate with the graphics card, via it's driver. The graphics susbsystem is essentially your logical driver, in this scenario.

Comment: Does the physical device driver be able to communicate with all types of logical device drivers? Because, I'll be able to work with my mouse in Ubuntu, Windows or any other OS that i install in my PC?

Comment: No, the physical device driver is OS specific, and these days typically comes in 32 and 64bit versions. For example, in Windows goes into the Device Manager and expand any of the devices. Then right click and go the properties. There will be a "driver" tab that lets you look at the driver.

Comment: But I was able to work with mouse, keyboard and speakers in Ubuntu as well alongside with Windows? How could it be possible if the physical device drivers are written OS-specific?

Comment: Each operating system ships with its own driver for all common hardware, such as mice and keyboards. When you installed the OS it installed a generic physical driver for the device, and the logical driver is talking to that.

Comment: Isn't a physical driver written by the hardware vendor and embedded in the device chip?

Comment: No, it's written by the hardware vendor and either distributed with the device or downloaded from their website! Hardware like mice and keyboards are pretty much identical these days, so it's possible to make a generic physical driver for them. However, if you think about it in terms of graphics cards, each card needs a specific driver, which you would either download or get on a disk when you buy the card. Most OS's ship with a generic graphic card driver, but to take advantage of the card's features you need a specific one from the vendor.

Comment: I think when you talk about hardware on a chip that you're thinking of firmware, such as the BIOS. In many ways this is another form of physical device driver.

Comment: So the physical driver need not always be inside the device chip. For those devices like mouse and keyboard which are most common, the physical driver can reside in the OS?

Comment: Physical device drivers are always in the OS. They know the specifics of the hardware and communicate with it on behalf of the OS. For every bit of hardware there is a physical driver that gets loaded into the OS. Yes there is firmware that runs directly on the hardware device, but you need a physical driver to know how to talk to it.

Comment: If the physical driver is interacting directly with the firmware of the device then why do we need logical driver?

Comment: It's all about abstraction. You don't want to have to know about the specifics of the underlying hardware so you talk to a logical driver where the API is always the same. It talks to the physical driver on your behalf, and at a lower level than you would want to. The physical driver know about the specifics of the device it drives, right down to the hardware level, which isn't something you, or the logical driver should care about.

Comment: For example, you're not interesting in the interrupts raised by your mouse when you move it, or which IO addresses you need to read from in order to get information on what buttons are pressed or how the mouse is moving. This is all handled by the physical driver. The logical driver lets you call an API, e.g. IsButtonPressed() and asks the physical driver, which then checks a mapped memory address before reporting back to the physical driver.

Comment: So when the mouse is clicked the firmware tells the physical driver and the physical driver tells the logical driver and this logical driver tells our program that mouse is clicked. Am i right?

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH especially for YOUR PATIENCE :) Accepted and +1.

Comment: Hello Sean, suppose I want to invoke a special API in physical device driver library (assume it has no abstraction at logical device driver library), is it possible to do from user application (user mode)? We are directly accessing physical driver API at user mode, so is this legal?

Comment: @MituRaj - There's nothing "illegal" about doing this. If the driver exposes a user-mode API then go ahead and use it!

Comment: So the system call is happening (to switch to Kernel mode) when we access the physical driver API, right? Not when the logical driver API is called?

Comment: @MituRaj - It's not possible to give a specific answer to such a general question.